# How can we get an autogenerated Id from the Table While Inserting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can we get an autogenerated Id from the Table While Inserting?

I have three tables

Project

ProjectXMilestone

Milestone

and on Insert of Milestone I also want to insert a row in 2nd Table so I need MilestoneId?so how can I get that?
I am using Linq.

Comment: What kind of Dataprovider do you use ? MSSQL ? Mysql ? And are you using a LinqToSql Class to get your data from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this its used for linq to sql

```
PractiseDataContext pDc = new PractiseDataContext();



// Here CustomerId is the Identity column(Primary key) in the 'CustomerDetails' table

CustomerDetail cust = new CustomerDetail();

cust.CustomerName = "LINQ to SQL";



pDc.CustomerDetails.InsertOnSubmit(cust);

pDc.SubmitChanges();



Response.Write(cust.CustomerId.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use LinqToSql, your DataContext is made from DB and your DB is set up with relations, you dont have to care about this at all. If there is a 1:n relation from Project to ProjectMilestones, your LinqToSql Class Project should have a Collection of ProjectMilestones, that you just have to fill.

You should be able to do something like:

```
Project pr = new Project();
pr.Milestones = new List<ProjectMilestone>();

pr.Milestones.add(new ProjectMilestone());
pr.Milestones.add(new ProjectMilestone());

DataContext.InsertOnSubmit(pr);
pr.SubmitChanges();
```